# Comparing Char to String

Tags: c++, c, arduino, char, boolean

I am currently doing a college project and most of my background comes from JS & Python.  I have an Arduino that is receiving data and using ArduinoJSON to take in settings and deserialize them.  I have it set up that the setting is a `const char* setting`.  Which can contain a range of data types (mostly int or bool).  But I am focused on trying to get a bool value from the char.

```
setting = doc["setting"];
if (setting == "true") {
  test = true;
} else if (setting == "false") {
  test = false;
}
```

I tried the above with no luck.  I also tried converting the char to a string but with no luck.  I also tried to use the .compare() function with no luck either.  What would you guys recommend?

Comment: `==` is not the correct way to compare C strings. Use `strcmp` or use C++ `std::string`.

Comment: If you want to compare null terminated strings, use the appropriate function, like `strcmp()`. As an aside, what should happen with `test` if neither test passes? Will it be indeterminate?

Comment: What happens if `setting == "frog"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `const char*`, the `==` operator will compare the pointer values rather than the text value (which will generally always be different since the data is stored in different locations). You could change it to:

```
if (strcmp(setting, "true") == 0) { test = true; }
else if (strcmp(setting, "false") == 0) { test = false; }
```

instead to get things working. Alternatively you could cast the setting to a `String` before doing the comparison and that should work as well:

```
String setting = String(doc["setting"]);
if (setting == "true") { test = true; }
else if (setting == "false") == 0) { test = false; }
```